# Invisibility Cloak unexpected interactions

Tags: werewolv.es

In the recent ext-327 game, a Furie with an Invisibility Cloak successfully protected another Coven member at night from an Omega Wolf kill, and the Furie did not get killed whilst visiting the other Coven member.  Whilst the Invis Cloak stops others from observing your visits, why did the Omega wolf not kill the visiting Furie?  I didn't realise Invis Cloaks could stop you from getting killed.   Could the OW just not see the Furie to kill them?

A similar unexpected interaction was observed in a previous game where a Beholder was unable to 'see' what the targeted Seer with Invis Cloak saw that night, whereas you would have thought they should have seen what the Seer saw from *inside* the cloak, as it were!

Are there guidelines for how we should view the Invis Cloak and its interactions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These interactions sound more like oversights / bugs than they do desired behaviour, so I'll add them to the list of things to look at.